# What data does AVAssetWriter metadata expect?

Tags: iphone, ios, metadata, avassetwriter, transcoding

I am trying to add metadata to a video I am transcoding via AVAssetWriter. I tried creating AVMutableMetadataItem object, inserting it in an array and setting metadata property of the AVAssetWriter object.  The result file does not include the metadata provided.

MediaInfo:

```
 AVMutableMetadataItem *mutableItem = [AVMutableMetadataItem metadataItem];
 mutableItem.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceQuickTimeUserData;
 mutableItem.key = AVMetadataQuickTimeUserDataKeyCredits;
 mutableItem.value = @"credit to me";

 assetWriter.metadata = [NSArray arrayWithObject:mutableItem];
```

Please help
Thanks

Comment: The docs say you should set the metadata before calling startWriting, I assume you're doing that. Maybe not all keys are supported: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777609/issue-with-setting-and-retrieving-the-value-of-avmetadatacommonkeycreator